# How can I represent my SQL INTEGER as floating point value using Hibernate's formula

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

To achieve better performance I want to store percent value with two digits after floating point as integer. E.g. 99.99% as 9999. How  can I convert back 9999 to 99.99%? I cannot recompile my java code to do this in Java according to some security reasons. So, how can I do this using HQL formula in my externalized mappings files? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL 5.5 worked:

> concat(value / 100.0, '%')

and

> cast(a.percentValue AS double)/100

failed with MySQLSyntaxErrorException